# File write access on ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask

I have this simple function.

```
@app.route('/save')
def save():
    with open("hello.txt", 'w') as file:
        file.write("hello")
        file.close()
    return "done"
```

But when I visit the `www.example.com/save` route, the server returns 500 Internal Server Error and the file is not written. What kind of permission should I set to this `Flask` app that resides in `/var/www/` so that the app can write file in the directory?

The error says: `I/O error(13): Permission denied`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make sure that python process user (in this case Flask application server) has write access to directory where you want to save you file. For example, if you would like to save file into the /var/www directory, make sure that the python process user has the correct access rights.

```
ls -al /var/www
sudo chown flask-user /var/www
```

Also, inside of the Flask route you should probably point to your save directory location instead of saving file into the process working directory (that's what's happening in your case). Something like this will work fine:

```
@app.route('/save')
def save():
    with open("/var/www/hello.txt", 'w') as file:
        file.write("hello")
        file.close()
    return "done"
```

Note: You should probably pick some other directory but /var/www for the place where you store your files.

Comment: Who is the flask-user? Is it my flask folder or app.py which initiates the app? What about www-data use since the server is apache? Sorry I am really confused here.

Comment: flask-user is user that your python application is running under.  If you are running python process as www-data user then you can just replace flask-user with www-data.

Comment: thanks. How do I find out who is running the python application?

Comment: @Zip You can just run ps aux | grep python and find the correct python process. How are you running your python application, apache mod python, uwsgi, or some other way?

Comment: I think it is wsgi. I followed the tutorial here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: When I enter the command (ps aux | grep python), I get this.
root     16763  0.0  0.1  11740   932 pts/1    S+   22:44   0:00 grep --color=auto python

So it is root that is running the process and not the www-data user?

Comment: @ZIp In that case it is probably www-data user, unless you changed default apache user.

Comment: @Zip Just grep for the flaskapp.wsgi since that's the python process wrapper script. When I told you to grep for the python process I didn't know how you are running your python application.

Comment: "ps aux | grep flaskapp.wsgi" is also run by root user. So who makes the actual "writing of file", www-data or root? Currently /var/www is owned by both www-data and root.

Comment: @ZIp It will be www-data if you didn't change default apache configuration. You are probably running your apache in worker MPM mode, and the initial process is run by root, but other child processes and threads will be run as www-data user.